# Error: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, python-2.x, connection-timeout

I am writing python script to open urls and read the content of an html page   and search for  some specific strings. Its working fine for few urls but when I tried with some 10 urls . 
I got error :

> urllib2.URLError:

I am writing multiple urls in a file and opening them on a  browser

I am using `python 2.7` here and `linux` device

I am able to open sites on my windows, Although its taking time to load.

This is a piece of my code:

---

```
import re
import sys
import os

import webbrowser

import urllib

import requests

import subprocess

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2

for urls in lines:

   req = urllib2.Request(urls, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})

      try:

        response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

        for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
            script.extract()    # rip it out
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

      ##After this here I am fetching strings using regex on text variable####

      except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.fp.read()
```

Comment: We're missing some important details. A example of how yout url list is being built as well as your import statement. Maybe worth printing urls in your loop to see what it's trying to connect to.

Comment: @AlphaTested I have added my import statement now. And I was printing my urls while testing but i did not put print statement here. Can you provide some insight for error messgae

Comment: The error had to say more than just "`urllib2.URLError:`". Show the complete error with the traceback.